# Pass Dictionary<string,string> from POST to GET method (as url parameters) ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, redirecttoaction

I have a problem. I'd like to pass a dictionary via RedirectToAction via RouteValueDictionary. Is there a possibility to do this?

I have a POST method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(MyViewModel _myViewModel)
{
    IDictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var item in _myViewModel)
    {
        parameters.Add(item.ValueId, item.ValueName);   
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Search", new RouteValueDictionary(parameters));
}
```

I'd like to have an url like this:

> http://localhost:26755/Searcher/Search?id1=value1&id2=value2&id3=value3

How the GET method should look like?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search( **what's here?** )
{
    (...)
    return View(myViewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we need to fix your `Search` action that performs the redirect. You should use an `IDictionary<string, object>` instead of `IDictionary<string, string>` if you want to get the desired query string parameters when redirecting:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(MyViewModel _myViewModel)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    foreach (var item in _myViewModel)
    {
        parameters.Add(item.ValueId, item.ValueName);   
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Search", new RouteValueDictionary(parameters));
}
```

and once you have done that in your target controller action you could just use the `QueryString` dictionary on the request:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search()
{
    // this.Request.QueryString is the dictionary you could use to access the
    // different keys and values being passed
    // For example:
    string value1 = this.Request.QueryString["id1"];

    ...

    // or you could loop through them depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve:
    foreach (string key in this.Request.QueryString.Keys)
    {
        string value = this.Request.QueryString[key];
        // do something with the value here
    }

    ...
}
```